# UIWebViewDelegate Problems

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios

I have a UIWebView set up in Interface Builder with the delegate set to File's Owner. I have webViewShouldStartLoad, webViewDidFinishLoad, webViewDidStartLoad, and webViewDidFailLoadWithError set up with NSLogs inside to see if they are working. webViewShouldStartLoad works perfectly, but the other three only work on the initial load. if I click a link to go to another page, the other three don't work. All the webpages load fine, but I cant get any of the webview delegate functions other than webViewShouldStartLoad to workAnyone have any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Is File's Owner the View Controller responsible for the UIWebView?

Make sure it is.

Second, I prefer to set the delegate in code. I takes away any mystery for novice developers. Interface Builder can be unclear at times, especially if you're unsure what the links look like in code. Remember, Interface Builder just saves you from writing certain code; everything you do in IB can be done in code.

Try this in the View Controller, usually in viewDidLoad:

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
```

(You don't HAVE to call 'self', I like to for reasons outside this thread)

Be sure that View Controller which owns the UIWebView implements UIWebViewDelegate in the header file.

UPDATE
Also, this from the dev site:

"Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled."

Have you done this?

Comment: Yes the File's Owner is the View Controller responsible for the UIWebView. I tried setting the delegate in the code as well, and the View Controller definitely implements the UIWebViewDelegate protocol. The weird thing is that webViewShouldStartLoad works fine. If it was a problem with setting the delegate, that shouldnt work, right?

Comment: Do you have multiple webViews? Are you setting the delegate to nil in the right place? Have you subclassed UIWebView at all? Other than that, I can't help unless you post some sample code. I can take a look at the class file if you feel comfortable sending it to me.

Comment: I do have multiple webViews, but they are in different view controllers. What do you mean setting the delegate to nil in the right place? Why and where would I have to set the delegate to nil?

Comment: The following from the UIWebViewDelegate Doc: "Important: Before releasing an instance of UIWebView for which you have set a delegate, you must first set the UIWebView delegate property to nil before disposing of the UIWebView instance. This can be done, for example, in the dealloc method where you dispose of the UIWebView."

Comment: I added [myWebView setDelegate:nil] to the dealloc but it is still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm just guessing at this point. When you alloc the UIWebView, add a retain count, are you using autoRelease? If so, don't. Are you using any other UIScrollView methods in the class? What type of class owns the UIWebView?

Comment: I figured out the problem, just not the solution yet. I am using parts of this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dJJgUqCH0w&feature=PlayList&p=E97B882FB8C8C0D6&index=0&playnext=1 to animate a view which contains the webview, in and out. for some reason the view never gets dealloc'd even in the tutorial. I just can't find a fix quite yet. Thanks so much for your help so far!!

Comment: Watched the video, can you take out the zooming animation code and test on a basic UINavigationController? I think the zooming code could be your problem though I'm not sure why. I don't think the contents of a pushed view are supposed to be retained after a view is popped off the stack. Therefore, you have two options, you can either recreate everything for the UIWebView code each time it's pushed, or make the ViewController which you're pushing an ivar of the first VC. That way, it should save everything (theorhetically) but you may have to set up your delegate each time.

Comment: and what would you say about this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html